# Is it possible to keep a pointer to a local variable beyond that variable's scope?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Suppose that I use this code:

```
int *pointer;
if(1) {
    int num = 5; // local variable, can't be used outside the if block.
    pointer = &num
}
```

Is this a safe way to keep track of the `num` variable? I know this code will work. But I think the compiler will use the old `num` memory to allocate new variables, causing `pointer` to refer to an unpredictable value. Is that true?

Comment: "I know this code will work." Not really. In any case, not reliably.

Comment: Maybe if you declare it static?  Never actually tried that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not safe. When the closing `}` of the `if` is reached, `num`'s lifetime ends, and the value of `pointer` becomes indeterminate. Using it thereafter invokes undefined behaviour.

What the compiler actually does depends, it may well use the storage that is used for `num` for another local variable that is not used before `num` comes into existence. Then using `pointer` to obtain the value that `num` had would definitely fail.

Answer (score 1):

No, it probably won't work, as you a trying to keep the value of an object that goes out of scope and the stack frame it belongs to will be destroyed. This might work once or twice, but it is always undefined behavior.